# JavaScript - replace a loop with old syntax

Tags: javascript

I have this code that is working successfully.

```
function maxChar() {  
      const charMap = {a:1, b:3, a:1}
      let max = 0
      let maxChar = ''

      for(let index in charMap) {
        if(max < charMap[index]){
          max = charMap[index]
          maxChar = index
        } 
      }

      return maxChar
    }

    console.log(maxChar())
```

It is returning on console `b` which is the letter that repeats most.

But I wanted to do the same thing with the old syntax.

How would I replace this?

```
for(let index in charMap) {//....
```

and the rest of the code

Comment: Replace all `const` and `let` by `var`.

Comment: what is the old syntax you want to use...? `for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(charMap).length; i++)`

Comment: It could be something more old than this example that doesn't use 'let index in..'.

Comment: @trincot I will keep it. i only want change the main parts that is the loop and what is inside into it.

Comment: btw, the wording suggest, you take an index. this might be right for arrays, but for objects, you get a key or a property name.

Comment: The loop you have in your code is as old as it can get. It was there in the first edition of EcmaScript (1997). The only thing that would not run in that version of JS are those `let` and `const`.

Comment: yes @ashish can you please make the complete code in the answer. If you do it, I will upvote it.

Comment: `Object.keys(charMap)` is not as old as the loop you already have... It was introduced in ES5, while the `for in` loop was there in ES1... I don't understand this question :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `tradition for loop` to loop over objects. 
You first need to get all the keys with `Object.keys(charMap)` and then loop over the keys.

```js
function maxChar() {  
    const charMap = {a:1, b:3, a:1}
    let max = 0
    let maxChar = ''
    const charMapKeys = Object.keys(charMap)

    for(let i = 0; i < charMapKeys.length; i++) {
        if(max < charMap[charMapKeys[i]]){
            max = charMap[charMapKeys[i]]
            maxChar = charMapKeys[i]
        } 
    }

    return maxChar
}

console.log(maxChar())
```

> PS: But it is advisable you use `for  ... in` loop to iterate over objects, as it is much cleaner and is supported since very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The `for .. in` loop syntax has been there since the first edition of EcmaScript. The only thing to adapt are those `let` and `const`: change them by `var`.

```js
function maxChar() {  
  var charMap = {a:1, b:3, a:1};
  var max = 0;
  var maxChar = '';
  for (var index in charMap) {
    if (max < charMap[index]) {
      max = charMap[index];
      maxChar = index;
    } 
  }
  return maxChar
}

console.log(maxChar());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the key without another variable for the max value.

For having an ES5 compliant code, change all variable declarations to `var` statements.

```js
function maxChar() {
    var charMap = { a: 1, b: 3, a: 1 },
        maxKey,
        key;

    for (key in charMap) {
        if (!maxKey || charMap[maxKey] < charMap[key]) {
            maxKey = key;
        }
    }
    return key;
}

console.log(maxChar());
```